# Next.js with Mongoose - Is there a central place to initiate connection?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, next.js

I reviewed the example of building an app with Next.js and Mongoose here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mongodb-mongoose

In this example, they built a function that makes the connection to the database as well as caches it for hot reloads. They put it in a file called `dbConnect.js`:

```js
let cached = global.mongoose

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongoose = { conn: null, promise: null }
}

async function dbConnect() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn
  }

  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      bufferCommands: false,
    }

    cached.promise = mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts).then((mongoose) => {
      return mongoose
    })
  }
  cached.conn = await cached.promise
  return cached.conn
}

export default dbConnect
```

Then, in every server-side-rendered page, they imported the `dbConnect` function, and in the `getServerSideProps` function, they called on it. For example, a page that fetches only a single item from the database has the following call:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({ params }) {
  await dbConnect()

  const pet = await Pet.findById(params.id).lean()
  pet._id = pet._id.toString()

  return { props: { pet } }
}
```

Is there any central location where I can place the call to `dbConnect` that will only run once when the server starts? I don't want to need to remember to include it with every new page I create.

I tried to call it in `_app.tsx` but that completely broke the entire app. I don't want to use the `getInitialProps` function because I have a few static pages in my app, and to my understanding using that function will force all pages to be server-side rendered. Is there any other way to initiate the connection when the server starts?

Comment: `getInitialProps` will not force your pages to be server rendered. You can still statically generated pages with the `export` function.

Comment: You can always abstract the things you would have to add into your `getInitialProps` function into another function and import that one on each page. Eventually each page needs that function for next to work.

Comment: OK. So, when you say "export function" you mean the Static HTML export (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export)? Can I use that feature to export only selected pages while all others are server-rendered? Thanks

Comment: I think you're confused as to what these two things do. Export is exporting static html files... of the entire website that has `getStaticPaths` defined. SSR dos all the same thing but on the fly while caching... so the normal SSR is what it sounds like you're looking for

Comment: Oh, okay. I read the docs again after your comment, and I think I get it now. `getInitialProps` only shuts off the automatic static optimization. I thought it completely disables the generation of static pages. I think I get it now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

u can define connection in

> next.config.js

and i want to mention that "import" statement not work there so try to use require

example

```
const connectDB = require('path to connection.js(where u define logic for connection)');
connectDB();
```

or implement connection logic there only

Comment: Are you sure about this? I tried this but it's not working